# Attempting to centre the page

Tags: html, css

Never had a problem trying to do this before.

I am attempting to centre the entire page.

Some code:

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#333333;
font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:0.85em;
}

#container{
width:960px;
float:left;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with that?
Anyone got any general problems it could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must remove `float: left` from `#container`. Other than that, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `float:left` should not be there. If you have trouble with showing floated elements in your container, you might want to add `overflow: hidden;` so the container expands when it has floated children in it.

For older versions of IE (below 7) `margin: 0 auto` is not supported: Add `text-align: center;` to your body and `text-align: left;` to your container to fix that.

Comment: `text-align: center` is only needed for **older than IE6**, *or* newer versions of IE in "Quirks Mode". Adding a valid doctype such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` will fix that.

Comment: Check it in IE6 here: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ + http://jsfiddle.net/EXrRu/show/.

Comment: Thanks! The coolest part: I didn't know that the url-suffix `show` for jsFiddle gives the created fiddle on a clean html page. That is most awesome!